# What does term "Security Holding" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have recently been informed by a government office of the United Kingdom that an account balance is X pounds on cash and Y pounds "in a security holding".

What does/might the term "security holding" mean to a UK government office?

Comment: Hard to say without more details. What sort of account is it? The word security covers a range of financial instruments, although at the risk-averse end of the spectrum. Could be some sort of National Savings product or bond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal phrasing is 'in securities', meaning bonds, shares, or the like. The singular seems to indicate that the holding consists of just one financial instrument, perhaps one issue of government bonds. The significance is that though the securities (unlike cash) will presumably be appreciating in value, they cannot be liquidated immediately when the time comes to close the account.